# Modify the covariance matrix of a vector to obtain a new vector with a given variance after matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, variance, covariance

I have a covariance matrix A that is used to generate a vector X. The vector X is then multiplied with a transformation matrix T to give a new vector Y. The vector Y now needs to have a pre-defined variance, sigma. How can I edit the matrix A such that after the transformation, Y has a variance sigma?

Comment: Do you mean that $X$ is a random vector with covariance matrix $A$?

Comment: And if $Y$ is a random vector, what does it mean to "have variance sigma"? Or is sigma the desired covariance matrix of $Y$?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, X is a random vector with covariance matrix A. Also, sigma is the desired variance of Y.

Comment: My point is that in general $Y$ is a vector, so "variance" is not really defined. Unless you mean that $T$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix so that $Y$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with covariance matrix $A$, and if $T$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, then $Y=TX$ is a random vector with covariance matrix $TAT^\top$.

Comment: $+1$ In practice, it may also be helpful to know that $T$ may be found using e.g. [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: Thanks! However, what I'm wondering is - if I want Y to have a variance of, say 0.1, is there a way to know what operations/changes would be required in A if the T is fixed?