# Find linear transformation to shape covariance matrix.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, covariance

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and $T$ be a $n \times n$ matrix.

Then $Y=TX$ is a random vector with covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma} = T \Sigma T^\top$.

With known $\Sigma$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ how to calculate $T$? Generally $\Sigma$ will not be diagonal.

There are closely related question ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3969505/modify-the-covariance-matrix-of-a-vector-to-obtain-a-new-vector-with-a-given-var?rq=1)) which suggest that Cholesky decomposition might be helpful, but I don't see how.

**[UPDATE]**

I found the answer if $\Sigma$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ are positive definite. How to get the solution if this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366111/closed-form-solution-for-xaxt-b/366116?noredirect=1#comment1005992_366116) question which which is quite similar.

Given the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ as

$$\hat{\Sigma} = MM^T$$
$$\Sigma = LL^T$$

then we can follow that $M^{-1}TLL^TT^T[M^T]^{-1} = I$, so $M^{-1}TL = Q$ with an orthogonal Matrix $Q$ and thus

$$T=MQL^{-1}$$ is a solution for any orthogonal $Q$.

Validating this for an example with $Q=I$ and
$$ \Sigma = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ -0.5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -0.5 \\ 0 & 0 & -0.5 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$
$$\hat{\Sigma} = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0.5 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\ 0.5 & 1 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\ 0.2 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.5 \\ 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.5 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

From that we get a lower triangle Matrix for T:

$$ T = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.47 & 0.53 & 0.86 & 0 \\ 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.96 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

With the desired property $\hat{\Sigma} = T \Sigma T^\top$.

BUT for using Cholesky it is neccessary that $\hat{\Sigma}$ and $\Sigma$ are positive definite. So it will not work for e.g.

$$ \Sigma = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & -0.5 & 0 & -1 \\ -0.5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -0.5 \\ -1 & 0 & -0.5 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$